# Plotting heat maps from data source

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to create an algorithm which allows me to create a heatmap for datasets consisting of the amount of points 10 basketball players achieve from January to June. I tried using seaborn in jupytor notebook, however, I kept encountering errors. Attached is my code and the error that came with it. Any idea how to solve it?
ps: the file 'player.csv' is a document with the first column as the plyaer's name, and the remaining 6 columns representing the points each player obtained every month.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv("player.csv")
data.pivot('JAN','FEB','MAR','APRI','MAY','JUNE')
data = sns.heatmap(data)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TypeError
5
6 data = pd.read_csv("player.csv")
----> 7 data.pivot('JAN','FEB','MAR','APRI','MAY','JUNE')
8 data = sns.heatmap(data)

TypeError: pivot() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 7 were given

Comment: You may want to give a small sample of the CSV (so people can understand it's structure). That being said it looks like you are using pivot wrong. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 0):

Your error is pretty explicit, that's [not how one uses `pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping)

However, in your specific case and if I understand your question correctly, you don't need to use `pivot`. I think

```
data = pd.read_csv("player.csv", index_col=0)
data = sns.heatmap(data)
```

should suffice, but it's impossible to know for sure without seeing the data.